# Compare the value of an attribute to some other value in a generated list

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2

I put this code in my view.phtml file to retrieve a list of an attribute's values in all product page.

```
 <?php $attribute_code = "my_attribute_code" ?>
 <?php $attribute_details = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("catalog_product", $attribute_code) ?>
 <?php $options = $attribute_details->getSource()->getAllOptions(false) ?>
     <ul>
         <?php foreach($options as $option): ?>
             <li>
             <?php echo $option['label']; ?>
             </li>
         <?php endforeach; ?>
     </ul>
```

Now, I need to highlight, (for example with just a simple css font-weight:bold;)
the value in the list that corresponding to the product.

For example, if my_attribute_code is color_tone

with value : very light; light; medium; medium dark; dark;

and if the product has this attribute set to light,

Then the list that I retrieve on it's page should be :

very light

**light**

medium

medium dark

dark

Comment: what happened with the update? Also have you tested what each variable is outputting yet?

Comment: try the latest addition to my answer... there's php errors on everything you've posted in your updates. The last one has closed the if statement before the else section. Also, make sure your variables have been declared correctly, eg. $_product.

Comment: yeah, if you're getting a blank page you've got a problem with variables most likely or maybe a syntax error. Your issue here is php related not really a magento one. My advice is turn on error hints, check all of your syntax and variables are correct. Also, based on your earlier posts, there's a high chance you've got other errors in the file which is why I asked for the full code.

Comment: whereever the code is, yes. You still never told me what the result was of just echo'ing those two variables?

Comment: good, now what happened when you did that?

Comment: include an example of the output of one loop iteration. If it's easier add `break;` after the final `echo`.

Comment: i meant the break after the echo statement and anyway that wasn't the important part. The output of one loop iteration was what I wanted. The break was solely for your benefit to clean it up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[EDIT]**

I removed this string: `;?>)`
from the first conditional statement

```
<?php if ($_product->getResource()->getAttribute('my_attribute_code')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) === $option['label']): ?>
```

and everything looks fine

```
 <?php $attribute_code = "my_attribute_code" ?>
 <?php $attribute_details = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("catalog_product", $attribute_code) ?>
 <?php $options = $attribute_details->getSource()->getAllOptions(false) ?>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach($options as $option): ?>
      <li>
      <?php if ($_product->getResource()->getAttribute('my_attribute_code')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) === $option['label']): ?>
         <p style="font-weight:bold;"><?php echo $option['label']; ?></p>
      <?php else: ?>
         <p><?php echo $option['label']; ?></p>
      <?php endif; ?>
      </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `var_dump($_product->getData());`? If you see your attribute code listed there you should be able to find it with `$_product->getData('my_attribute_code');`.

Another option is something like this

```
$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('my_attribute_code')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

This is not valid php.

```
<?php if ($_product->getResource()->getAttribute('my_attribute_code')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);?>) == $option['label']) ?>
```

It should be

```
<?php if ($_product->getResource()->getAttribute('my_attribute_code')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) === $option['label']){ echo 'success'; }  ?>
```

You should also be echo'ing both values first so you can see what data they output so you know that they are the ones you need to compare.

The final thing should look something like this.

```
 <?php $attribute_code = "my_attribute_code" ?>
 <?php $attribute_details = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("catalog_product", $attribute_code) ?>
 <?php $options = $attribute_details->getSource()->getAllOptions(false) ?>
 <ul>
     <?php foreach($options as $option): ?>
         <li>
         <?php if ($_product->getResource()->getAttribute('my_attribute_code')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);?>) === $option['label']): ?>
             <p style="font-weight:bold;"><?php echo $option['label']; ?></p>
         <?php else: ?>
             <p><?php echo $option['label']; ?></p>
         <?php endif; ?>
         </li>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
 </ul>
```

Comment: well i'd suggest rendering them on the page first to see what they output. Then if one works you should replace it, yes.

Comment: if using $product->getData('my_attribute_code') returns the attribute use that, no? You should output both that and $option["label"] so you can see exactly what they return.

Comment: why is this '$option["label"]''$option["value"]' in quotes? this will obviously break as it's not correct php

Comment: like i said, forget about the if statement to begin with. Just echo the results of each variable so you can see exactly what's being output. The question is also where you should add the code if you're getting errors. It's too difficult to tell what's wrong if you just put one line

Comment: set up a chat and i'll have a look

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23101/compare-the-value-of-an-attribute-to-some-other-value-in-a-generated-list

Comment: use the question here to paste your code like i said before

Comment: if you don't paste exactly what you've done in the question it's not possible for me to see where you're going wrong. The fact that you had quotes around the variables to begin with suggests your php knowledge is very limited so i'm guessing you've made more mistakes which won't be reflected if i try the code in my files

Comment: The rules of the site dictate that all issues regarding the question go in the question. If you don't do that no one will attempt to answer your issue. Fyi your question still shows the quoted variable .

Comment: if this `<?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('my_attribute_code')->getFrontend()->getv‌​alue($_product);?>` displays the products value for that attribute then use that to compare to the variable you are checking it against. If you're still having problems you should echo the variable you're comparing it to so you can see what is getting output there

Comment: updated answer just now